# How to implement MySQL statement similar like loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, union

I have one table1, has field like below.

```
rsid  pos
123   10000
234   10001
567   10008
```

and another table2 has only one field

```
rsid
123
345
...
```

So, my target is to find the rsids whose position is within certain range.
for example, I want to find rsid in table1 whose position is within +- 10000 position of the rsids in table2, for example  123.

I can write sql for specific rows, which is like below

```
select *
from table1
where pos > (select pos from table1 where rsid=123)-100000
  and pos < (select pos from table1 where rsid=123)+100000;
```

but in table2, there are thousands of rows, and finally I want to union all the qualified rsid into one table, is there any way like for loop to union all the results?
Thanks a lot for your help?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your kind reply. A more specific example would be like below. Suppose the table1 has only following entries.

```
rsid  pos
123   10000
234   10001
567   10008
100   20015
101   20001
108   50000
```

and another table2 has only such entries.

```
rsid
123
100
```

Then the expect result would be

```
rsid  pos
234   10001
567   10008
101   20001
```

because 234,567 are within +-10000 of 123 and 101 are within +-10000 of 101.

Answer (score 0):

Must admit: I don't really understand the question. 
so this is what I think you mean:

1) find all RSIDs within 100,000 of a specific RSID

2) create those results into a new table. (which looping and union aren't needed if you simply use the create table from a select syntax.

3) Not sure what table2 has to do with anything but I think you only want RSID positions which exist in both table1 and table2.

```
    Create table NEWTable
    Select RSID, pos
    from table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.RSID = T2.RSID
    WHERE t1.pos between  
      (select pos from table1 where rsid=123)-100000 
  and (select pos from table1 where rsid=123)+100000;
```

Comment: As for t2, actually I only need to  find all RSIDs within 100,000 of  RSIDs which are in t2

Comment: Sample data would help. along with some expected results. I believe the join between T1, T2 gives you those IDs.  But since the join eliminates entries in T1 if they don't exist in T2 and vice-versa I'm still not sure what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. A more specific example would be like below. Suppose the table1 has only following entries.

rsid  pos
123   10000
234   10001
567   10008
100   20015
101   20001
108   50000

and another table2 has only such entries.
rsid
123
100


Then the expect result would be


rsid  pos
234   10001
567   10008
101   20001

because 234,567 are within +-10000 of 123 and 101 are within +-10000 of 101.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.pos from 
(select distinct t1.pos from t1 join t2 
 where t1.pos between t2.pos-20000 and t2.pos+20000) t1 
where t1.pos not in (select * from t2);
```